# Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions on signOut()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm using vuex and firebase to implement user authentication following the instruction of [vuegram](https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram). I tried many ways to detach firebase listeners, the only one that stop warning error is the following:

```
var unsubscribe=fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
    if(user){
        store.commit('setCurrentUser',user)
        store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')

        fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
            store.commit('setUserProfile', doc.data())
        })
    }
})
unsubscribe();
```

However, the code above just stop warning on signOut(), I can't update data anymore.

My store.js file:

```
var unsubscribe=fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
    if(user){
        store.commit('setCurrentUser',user)
        store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')

        fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
            store.commit('setUserProfile', doc.data())
        })
    }
})

export const store=new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        currentUser:null,
        userProfile:{}
    },
    actions:{
        clearData({commit}){
            commit('setCurrentUser',null)
            commit('setUserProfile', {})
        },
        fetchUserProfile({ commit, state }) {
             fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).get().then(res => {
                commit('setUserProfile', res.data())

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
        updateProfile({ commit, state }, data) {
            let displayName = data.displayName

            fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).set({
                displayName: displayName
            }, {merge:true}).then(function() {
                alert("Document successfully written!");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                alert("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
        }
    },
    mutations:{
        setCurrentUser(state, val) {
            state.currentUser = val
        },
        setUserProfile(state, val) {
            state.userProfile = val
        }
    }
})
```

The signOut method:

```
signOut: function(){
        fb.auth.signOut().then(()=> {
            this.$store.dispatch('clearData')
            this.$router.push('login')
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

My firebase rule:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid!=null;
```

Comment: because you are still subscribing for data. First unsubscribe then call signout :)

Comment: Where should I call unsubscribe()? If I call it in clearData(), it's undefined

Comment: See the [documentation on detaching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you still have an active listener when you log out, the system detects that the client has lost permission to read that data and rejects the listener. This means you need to remove the listener before signing out to prevent the error message.

See the [documentation on detaching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), you first get a reference to the unsubscribe function when you attach the listener:

```
unsubscribe = fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
    store.commit('setUserProfile', doc.data())
})
```

And then call that function before signing out:

```
signOut: function(){
    unsubscribe();
    fb.auth.signOut().then(()=> {
        this.$store.dispatch('clearData')
        this.$router.push('login')
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still gives me error. Is it necessary to catch this error? Why the signOut method doesn't detach the listener for us automatically?

Comment: There are plenty of use-case where listeners can remain active when the user signs out. But in your case the listener gets removed, it just explicitly tells you that it got cancelled since this may be a problem. If that is the result you want, you can ignore the error if you prefer. But if you still get the error, you still have a listener somewhere that requires an authenticated user and I personally strongly prefer knowing what my code is doing at such a point.

Comment: Thanks Puff, I just use `get()` method to get data instead of `onSnapshot()`, and the error is gone.

Comment: having to remove the listener before signing out is ridiculous. it should be implicit at sign out, once firestore instance knows which ones you need signing and there is no possibility of accessing one of those without permission. Sign out should just unsubscribe all of them automatically, Because of this you necessarily need to keep track of every snapshot event... now imagine this on a big application like mine. Doesnt make sense

Comment: When a listener loses access to the underlying data it is automatically cancelled. To ensure you are aware of this happening, this raises the error event for the listener that is cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a logout button on many pages just navigate to a different page and call logout from there. Then you don't have to litter your code with unsubscribes.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the `onsnapshot` permission denied error, just handle the error [(see Firestore docs)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors) without doing anything at your `firebase auth`:

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
  collection(db, "cities"), 
  (snapshot) => {
    // ...
  },
  (error) => {
    // Handle your error here. It will not log in the console anymore,
    // and the listener has already been automatically detached at this point.
  });
```

After the error, the listener will be automatically detached, you do not have to call the `unsubscribe` again:

> After an error, the listener will not receive any more events, and
> there is no need to detach your listener.

So just sign out your user with your `firebase auth`, as though it is unaware of your `onsnapshot` listener.

Answer (score -3):

You can also check your `Firestore rules`.

[image]

If this is what is there:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Change to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that this is insecure and for dev purposes only. To understand how Firestore rules work, check out [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw).